# Maximal number of regions obtained by joining n points around a circle by straight lines

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Let's define *f(n)* as the maximal number of regions obtained by joining n points around a circle by straight lines. For example, two points would split the circle into two pieces, three into four, like this:
[image]

Make sure when you are drawing the lines, you don't have an intersection of more than two lines.

### Your task

Given a number *n*, print *f(n)*.

Test cases:

```
 n | f(n)   
---+-----
 1 |   1
 2 |   2
 3 |   4
 4 |   8
 5 |  16
 6 |  31
 7 |  57
 8 |  99
 9 | 163
```

<sup>You can see more [here](http://oeis.org/A000127/list).</sup>

Using built-in sequence generators is not allowed.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

If you guys want the formula, here it is:

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
Tr@Binomial[#,{0,2,4}]&
```

Uses the formula in the question.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```
n=>(((n-6)*n+23)*n/6-3)*n/4+1
```

Uses a formula given in OEIS.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
5Ḷc@’S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NeG4tmNA4oCZUw&input=&args=OA) | [Verify test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NeG4tmNA4oCZUwrFvMOH4oKsRw&input=&args=MSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDk)

#### Explanation

Uses the OEIS formula `((n-1)C4 + (n-1)C3 + ... + (n-1)C0)`.

```
5Ḷc@’S    Main link.  Args: n

5         Yield 5.
 Ḷ        Lowered range: yield [0,1,2,3,4].
    ’     Yield n-1.
   @      Swap operands of the preceding dyad, 'c'.
  c       Combinations: yield [(n-1)C0, (n-1)C1, (n-1)C2, (n-1)C3, (n-1)C4].
     S    Sum: return (n-1)C0 + (n-1)C1 + (n-1)C2 + (n-1)C3 + (n-1)C4.
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and great first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
c3ḶḤ¤S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YzPhuLbhuKTCpFM&input=&args=MTA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YzPhuLbhuKTCpFMKxbzDh-KCrEc&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOQ).

#### How it works

```
c3ḶḤ¤S  Main link. Argument: n

    ¤   Combine the three links to the left into a niladic chain.
 3        Yield 3.
  Ḷ       Unlength; yield [0, 1, 2].
   Ḥ      Unhalve; yield [0, 2, 4].
c       Combinations; compute [nC0, nC2, nC4].
     S  Sum; return nC0 + nc2 + nC4.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
q5:qXns
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cTU6cVhucw&input=OQ) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBxNTpxWG5z&input=MTo5).

#### Explanation

Uses the formula (from OEIS): *a*(*n*) = *C*(*n*−1, 4) + C(*n*−1, 3) + ... + C(*n*−1, 0)

```
q      % Implicit input. Subtract 1
5:q    % Array [0 1 2 3 4]
Xn     % Binomial coefficient, vectorized
s      % Sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7,<del>50</del> 47 bytes

```
int c(int n){return(n*n*(n-6)+23*n-18)*n/24+1;}
```

Uses the formula (from OEIS)

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>27</s> 26+3 = 29 bytes

3 bytes added for the -v flag

```
::::6-**$f8+*f3+-+*f9+,1+n
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Ojo6OjYtKiokZjgrKmYzKy0rKmY5KywxK247&input=&args=LXYgOQ)

A byte saved thanks to *Martin Ender*.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 25 bytes

```
sum(choose(scan(),0:2*2))
```

`scan()` takes the input `n` from stdin, which is passed to `choose` along with `0:2*2`. This latter term is `0` to `2` (i.e. `[0, 1, 2]`) multiplied by 2, which is `[0, 2, 4]`. Since `choose` is vectorized, this calculates `n choose 0`, `n choose 2`, `n choose 4`, and returns them in a list. Finally, `sum` returns the sum of these numbers, surprisingly enough.

I don't think that this can be golfed further but I would be very happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: I was 2 seconds from submitting the same solution, nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 73 bytes

```
(load library)
(d D(q((N)(+(/(*(s N 1)N(s N 2)(s N 3))24)(/(*(s N 1)N)2)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmhDoAgFAXQzle8eK8GB1rsZP4BR2FDUaH49c/NZDrh9Hw8JbdTFaXGJCVvd7wfGiTxuIBAjJgwoEkQy/Dp@DGTbuF/6WjVYI@neIHtVVZSXw)

From Giuseppe.

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 90 bytes

```
(d C(q((N K)(i K(i N(a(C(s N 1)(s K 1))(C(s N 1)K))0)1
(d D(q((N)(a(a(C N 0)(C N 2))(C N 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs9CoAwGEN3T5Ex2ay4OOtW6B0qLoX67@Lp64eCQ3iQvFxpuXM6t1I4oedOBngxwVsCI3ueCHAyeIP@wku1XGW34b3JZNNtq/Wi0ce2MK9xQk7jEY@74hw3DKC7VnRSeQA)

Comment: You're only using `library` for `+` which is rather wasteful so just use `a` twice: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs9CoAwGEN3T5Ex2ay4OOtW6B0qLoX67@Lp64eCQ3iQvFxpuXM6t1I4oedOBngxwVsCI3ueCHAyeIP@wku1XGW34b3JZNNtq/Wi0ce2MK9xQk7jEY@74hw3DKC7VnRSeQA) I think neil's answer is using floordiv which is why it doesn't port quite right.

Comment: Could port the [R answer](https://tio.run/##TcmhDoAgFAXQzle8eK8GB1rsZP4BR2FDUaH49c/NZDrh9Hw8JbdTFaXGJCVvd7wfGiTxuIBAjJgwoEkQy/Dp@DGTbuF/6WjVYI@neIHtVVZSXw) as well...

Answer (score 2):

## dc, 21

```
?ddd6-*23+*6/3-*4/1+p
```

[RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)-ised version of [@Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96890/11259).

#### Test output:

```
$ for i in {1..9}; do dc -e "?ddd6-*23+*6/3-*4/1+p" <<< $i; done
1
2
4
8
16
31
57
99
163
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 9 bytes

```
+4&!+2!<:
```

Uses the formula `C(n-1, 2) + C(n, 4) + n = C(n, 0) + C(n, 2) + C(n, 4)`.

### Usage

```
   f =: +4&!+2!<:
   (,.f"0) >: i. 10
 1   1
 2   2
 3   4
 4   8
 5  16
 6  31
 7  57
 8  99
 9 163
10 256
   f 20
5036
```

### Explanation

```
+4&!+2!<:  Input: integer n
       <:  Decrement n
     2     The constant 2
      !    Binomial coefficient C(n-1, 2)
 4&!       Binomial coefficient C(n, 4)
    +      Add them
+          Add that to n and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
2Ý·scO
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MsOdwrdzY08&input=OQ)

**Explanation**

Straight implementation of the OEIS formula `c(n,4) + c(n,2) + c(n,0)`

```
2Ý       # range: [0,1,2]
  ·      # multiply by 2: [0,2,4]
   s     # swap list with input
    c    # combinations
     O   # sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-89 Basic, 57 Bytes

```
:Def a(a)=Func
:Return nCr(n,0)+nCr(n,2)+nCr(n,4)
:End Func
```

Throwback to old times.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can't you remove the `)` on the last `nCr`?

Comment: @Oliver Hi "Not Sure", I am also Not Sure. (Idiocracy is a great movie).

Comment: Isn't `nCr(n,0)` always equal to 1?

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 31 bytes

```
=(A1^2*(A1-6)+A1*23-18)*A1/24+1
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnhDou7yktFXJp2A3?e=IasfW5)

Using one of OEIS formulas

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 29 bytes

```
[ "\0"[ nCk ] with map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZecn5uUmZcIFM5MLlbITi3KS81RKE4tLE3NS04thqgpzctMzk9JVSgoSi0pqSwoyswrgUgUJealAxVZc3FZKkQb6iTF/o9WUGJiiTFQilbIc85WiFUozyzJAKotUDi3WCH2P4ih9x8A)

You might not be able to see them here, but there are literal 2 and literal 4 control codes embedded in the string. It's a shorter version of `{ 2 4 0 }`. You can see them for sure on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
D╣5@HΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=ROKVozVASM6j&input=Ng)

Explanation:

```
D╣5@HΣ
D       decrement input
 ╣      push that row of Pascal's triangle
  5@H   first 5 values
     Σ  sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 4 bytes

```
3ʁdƈ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwiM8qBZMaIIiwiIiwiNCJd)

Simply an implementation of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 35 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>(n*n*(n-6)+23*n-18)*n/24+1
```

Uses the same formula as [numberknot's java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96903/46901).

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```
@(m)binocdf(4,m-1,.5)*2^m/2
```

This is an anonymous function.

[**Try it at Ideone**](http://ideone.com/ClbMv4).

#### Explanation

This is based on the OEIS formula *a*(*m*) = *C*(*m*−1, 4) + *C*(*m*−1, 3) + ... + C(*m*−1, 0), where *C* are binomial coefficients. The [binomial distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

[image]

for *k* = 4, *n* = *m*−1 and *p* = 1/2 gives 2<sup>*m*−1</sup>*a*(*m*).

Comment: @Oliver That would probably end up being longer, because then it's not the distribution function. I would need the probability (mass) function and sum; something like `@(m)sum(binopdf(0:2:4,m,.5)*2^m)`